# iOS webview height pin (xamarin or code)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a Xamarin iOS app that is created with a storyboard. The storyboard is set to view as iPhone 5. I have a webview as below that fits the screen fine. When run on an iPhone 6 plus, it seems to grow fine and fills the entire iphone 6 plus screen. However when used on an iphone 4, a web page will fall off the bottom of the screen... which indicates to me that the webview is too big.

[image]

I don't know why it seems to scale up but not down. I need the bottom of the webview to always pin to the bottom of the screen. How can I do this? I have tried the UI constraint icons but they never seem to work as expected. Can this just be done in code instead? Even in iOS objective-c would help as I can convert it to c#.

Any pointers would be great!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works on iPhone 5 and the 6 versions because iPhone6/6+ uses a compatibility mode. Resolution of iPhone 4 is smaller. Try single clicking the web view to switch to constraint mode (you'll see T and H shaped handles).
Drag the T shaped ones to  the top, left, right and bottom border of the view controller's view. That will constrain height and with to the parent view's size.

Comment: It wasn't working but I noticed a little triangle in the bottom suggesting missing constraints. This resolved it.. with quite a lot of fiddling!